# Can one only believe in perceptions?

Tags: belief, propositions

In the following example provided by [SEOP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/#Repr), Kai is said to believe a proposition:

> for example, when Kai reads that astronomers no longer classify Pluto as a planet, he acquires a new belief (in this case, the belief that astronomers no longer classify Pluto as a planet).

However is this indeed the belief he involuntarily acquires? Would he not instead (from reading said proposition) "believe that he perceives/read that astronomers no longer classify Pluto as a planet."? Then of course he involuntarily acquires the belief that "he percieves that he percieves ..." and it infinitely regresses hereon.

**So can one only believe in perceptions of propositions, perceptions of beliefs of perceptions, but not propositions alone?** (In  a non-doxastic venturing manner of course)

Comment: As Ibn Arabi said; I have created perception in you only in order to be the object of My Perception.
If then you perceive Me, you perceive yourself.
But you cannot perceive Me through yourself.
It is through My Eyes that you see Me and see yourself,
Through your eyes you cannot see Me. https://blogs.harvard.edu/sulaymanibnqiddees/2017/05/14/ibn-arabi-my-beloved/

Comment: I suggest you to read this doctoral thesis to much undrestand Ibn Arabi's philosophy about Perception http://www.theses.fr/2004AIX10056

Comment: Read this Book which talk about Uncertainity and Perception. Thomas Lagner
Systems Thinking - Perception of Perception as Key.https://www.amazon.fr/Systems-Thinking-Perception-Key-ebook/dp/B07C9GNZHR

Comment: "He percieves that he percieves"? Perception is an act, it is not an entity that can, in turn, be perceived, see [The Phenomenological Fallacy](https://www.diametros.iphils.uj.edu.pl/diametros/article/view/889/1065). The nominalization, and the regress, is a linguistic artifact. He can reflect on his perception and form some beliefs about it, but that would not be perceiving, and he won't be able to do it infinitely many times.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry I should have stated "He believes that he perceives that he believes that he perceives".

Comment: In the Book of Fast and Slow thinking , Daniel Kaheneman defined Believe as; when your "Intuition" comes with "Imperetion". So as Jung defined" intuition "as "perception via the unconscious": using sense-perception only as a starting point, to bring forth ideas, images, possibilities, ways out of a blocked situation, by a process that is mostly unconscious.

Comment: Perception comes before intuition. It is conscious awareness – pre-thought. It is the space between our thoughts and arises from our senses.Daniel Kahneman, Thinking, Fast and Slow https://www.amazon.fr/Thinking-Fast-Slow-Daniel-Kahneman/dp/0374533555

Comment: Is there anything a human "imports" into his mind that is not a "perception"?